# Start Oracle Listener and view status failed

Tags: oracle11g

I have a Oracle database in my local computer. Like everyday, I must view status and start Oracle's listener before keep working. But today i got an error.

```
C:\Windows\system32>lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 20-DEC-2017 14:53:09

Copyright (c) 1991, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   64-bit Windows Error: 61: Unknown error
```

The "HOST" parameter missed the value. I tried to edit both files "listener.ora" and "tnsnames.ora" to solve the problem but nothing happened.

This is content of "listener.ora" file:

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: F:\PHUOC\OracleCSDL\product\11.2.0\dbhome_2\network\admin\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = F:\PHUOC\OracleCSDL\product\11.2.0\dbhome_2)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:F:\PHUOC\OracleCSDL\product\11.2.0\dbhome_2\bin\oraclr11.dll")
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = test
      (ORACLE_HOME = F:\PHUOC\OracleCSDL\product\11.2.0\dbhome_2)
      (PROGRAM = dg4odbc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:F:\PHUOC\OracleCSDL\product\11.2.0\dbhome_2\bin\oraclr11.dll")
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = LINKSQL
      (ORACLE_HOME = F:\PHUOC\OracleCSDL\product\11.2.0\dbhome_2)
      (PROGRAM = dg4msql)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:F:\PHUOC\OracleCSDL\product\11.2.0\dbhome_2\bin\oraclr11.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DESKTOP-E6UVA39)(PORT = 1521)) 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1522)) 
    )
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = F:\PHUOC\OracleCSDL
```

And this is content of "tnsnames.ora" file:

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: F:\PHUOC\OracleCSDL\product\11.2.0\dbhome_2\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER_SCADA =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

SCADA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = Scada)
    )
  )
sqlserver = 
(DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = test) 
    )


)

LINKSQL = 
(DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = 
    (PROTOCOL = TCP)
    (HOST = localhost)
    (PORT = 1521)
    )
    (ADDRESS = 
    (PROTOCOL = TCP)
    (HOST = localhost)
    (PORT = 1522)
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID=LINKSQL) 
    )


)
```

And then this is content of "sqlnet.ora" file:

```
# sqlnet.ora Network Configuration File: F:\PHUOC\OracleCSDL\product\11.2.0\dbhome_2\network\admin\sqlnet.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

# This file is actually generated by netca. But if customers choose to 
# install "Software Only", this file wont exist and without the native 
# authentication, they will not be able to connect to the database on NT.

SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)

NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
```

One more thing my "OracleTNSListener" is running, this is the image: [Image for Oracle Listener Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75GDQ.png)

I have searched for every webpage about Oracle but I could not found the solution. I think this is the last chance for me to solve the problem.

Please help me!

Thanks in advance. Hoping the help!

Answer (score 1):

After searched for all forums about Oracle where I could get help I solved my problem by remove Database Gateway for MSSQL. I dont know what happened but this is not the best answer. At least I can solve my problem.

Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to fix it the way as (a lot of) Windows problems are solved: restart the computer?

Comment: Yes i have restarted my computer. But I still get problem.